# What is the average wood consumption of a family in a wooden home?

Tags: banished

I am interested in getting an estimate of per capita wood consumption of individuals in wooden homes. Does wood consumption fluctuate based on the size of a family?

For example: base number X wood consumption + yx where y is the number of family members.

As a side note, how does a stone house modify this consumption?

Comment: Not having played the game myself, but if I was to use an equation on deciding how much wood it takes to warm a house I would make it determined by the size of the house not the number of people in the house. but this is pure speculation

Answer (score 2):

Per the tips thread on the /r/Banished subreddit:

"Wooden houses burn (very approximately) 30 firewood a winter, while stone houses burn roughly 15."

This also implies firewood consumption is per house, not per capita.

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/Banished/comments/1yu1eq/banished_discoveries_data_and_tips/