# When should I start to increase the size of population?

Tags: banished

I was upset when I started this game that I barely manage to fill the resources so I created a new game, aiming to grow the number of resources and maintain a good supply for the families.

However this time, I just realized that the people will not born new ones even though the house has still space ( I used 1 boarding house and 1 built with stone ) with the resources getting maxed every 30 seconds. Also that it's risky to increase population when I don't even have stable food source.

So, what are the conditions to be met before I start to grow the population since a little early might starve them and a little late is just too late (Some of the houses have partners < 50 years of age and still they won't create new ones)?

Answer (score 1):

The main points to consider are:
Do you want to play stable (it can be interesting to not)
Do you want to maintain the higher poulation
How many resources do you produce compared to your usage?
Do you have a stockpile of resources?

Consumption rates:

[Food is roughly 100 per citizen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/157392/101508)

[Firewood changes by building type](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/158170/101508)

Okay my personal starting setup is to build a forester (staffed by 1), gatherer (as many as you can spare) and hunting lodge (1), A woodcutter (1) and thats about it for the first season or so. Predominantly the first few years I aim at gathering a surplus of food.

A general recommendation that is put around is around 1 house per year for stable growth. However I tend to just put them down as I feel, often when there is a pair of youngsters available to match (unless i have little to no surplus).

I am not sure how the breeding works but I think that the rate slows as they age, I will edit this answer to include later.

Comment: How do I know that a year has passed?

Comment: First thing I do with every new game is to open a number of overviews, specifically the quick overview tab which details all the most important quick details (population, resources, happiness/health, and season/year). This can be opened by pressing the settings tab and one of the buttons in there (cannot remember which exactly)

Answer (score 0):

You know I would make sure you have enough firewood and wood.  I would get to a surplus of 500 firewood and 1000 food.   I wouldn't be afraid to grow too fast.   Make sure you have a few empty houses too.  If you see your crops are dying in the winter without being harvested definitely grow your population